# How to specify two dates in Autosys jil let’s say it has to run on two calendar dates 15th and 30th of each month?

Tags: autosys

I specified like below

run_calendar : 15CD & 30CD

Getting an error saying invalid keyword?

Tried many combinations “15CD” & “30CD” also 15CD,30CD still sane error.

Answer (score 1):

extended calendar can have such conditions.

Create an extended calendar as

```
extended_calendar: Cal_name
description: runs on 15th and 30th of every month
workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
non_workday:  
holiday:  
holcal: 
cyccal: 
adjust: 0
condition: MNTHD#15| MNTHD#30
```

Use this calendar for your job.

**MNTHD#nn**

Specifies that the schedule that is generated by the extended calendar includes the nnth  day of the month.

refer [broadcom.com on *Date Condition Keywords*](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0/scheduling/ae-scheduling/manage-your-calendars/date-condition-keywords.html) for more such combination of calendar conditions

Hope this helps.